# Minecraft Plugin - NullPointerException

Tags: java

Я учусь писать плагины для Bukkit/Spigot. В Java новичок.
В какой то момент я получил NullPointerException. Ошибка указывает на строку 13 класса Main.
Вот строка 13:

```
getCommand(cmds.playerinfocmd).setExecutor(cmds);
```

Весь код класса Main:

```
package com.testplugin;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

Commands cmds = new Commands(this);

public void onEnable() {
    
    Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Handler(), this);
    getCommand(cmds.playerinfocmd).setExecutor(cmds);
    
    getLogger().info("Test plugin enabled!");
    
}

public void onDisable() {
    
    getLogger().info("Test plugin disabled!");
    
}

}
```

Код класса commands:

```
package com.testplugin;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

public class Commands implements CommandExecutor{

Main plugin;
String playerinfocmd = "plinfo";

public Commands(Main plugin) {
    this.plugin = plugin;
}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    
    if(cmd.toString() != playerinfocmd) return true;
    
    Boolean hasperm = NoPermission("test.plinfo", sender); 
    
    if(!hasperm) {
        
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You don`t have permission");
        return true;
        
    }
    
    if(args.length != 1) {
        
        return false;
        
    }
    
    String playername = args[0];
    Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer(playername);
    if(player == null) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + playername + " is not defined");
        return true;
    }
    
    sender.sendMessage("IP: " + player.getAddress().getAddress());
    
    return true;
}

public Boolean NoPermission(String permission, CommandSender p) {
    
    if(!p.hasPermission(permission)) {
        
        return true;
        
    } else {
        
        return false;
        
    }
    
}

}
```

Код класса Handler:

```
package com.testplugin;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;

public class Handler implements Listener{

@EventHandler
public void Join(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    Player player = e.getPlayer();
    player.sendMessage("Привет, " + player.getName());
}

}
```

plugin.yml:

```
name: Test
main: com.testplugin.Main
version: 1.0
commands:
plinfo:
 description: Show player info
 usage: /info <Player>
```

Comment: getCommand(cmds.playerinfocmd) - проверяйте, что вы получаете в результате вызова этого метода. здесь возвращается null, а вызов любого метода , в т.ч. .setExecutor(cmds) у переменной, в которой хранится null, приведет к указанной ошибке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, я нашёл ошибку.
В файле plugin.yml отредактировал отступы
Вот правильный вариант

```
name: Test
main: com.testplugin.Main
version: 1.0
commands:
 plinfo:
  description: Shows player info
  usage: /plinfo <Player>
```

(Поставил пробел перед plinfo)